# Computing average without using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to compute average in html without clicking the button to show the result, every time when the input type text changed, the output will change too without clicking the button

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}

function divideBy() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br> 2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Multiply" />
  <input type="button" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: you should use `type="number"` for both input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `input` listener to both buttons:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (const input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = (Number(inputs[0].value) + Number(inputs[1].value)) / 2;
  });
}
```

```html
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br> 2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
<p>The Result is : <br>
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```